# New to Haskell - Trying to create associative xor chart

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-platform

I'm trying to create a associate xor chart on Haskell, which to my understanding, should come out true in every instance. Though, when i call my function I get: [True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True]. Can anyone see the mistake I made?

```hs
bools = [True, False]

xor_assoc = [   ((r || (p || q)) && not (r || (p && q)))
             == ((p || (r || q)) && not (p || (r && q)))
            | r <- bools,
              p <- bools,
              q <- bools]
```

Comment: `(p,q,r) = (False,False,True)`, lhs = False, rhs = True. Similar is the case for `(True, False, False)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your principle is wrong: `(r || (p && q)) /= (p || (r && q))`. Counter-example is `(p, q, r) = (T, F, F)` where we have

```
(F || (T && F)) /= (T || (F && F))
(F || F       ) /= (T || F       )
F               /= T
```

Notably, both `(||)` and `(&&)` are individually associative, but do not associate around one another.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are doing exactly. But the way you are doing list comprehension, it will generate all possible `2^3` cases. And your predicate returns `False`  in two of them.

When `(p,q,r) = (False,False,True)` then `(r || (p && q))` becomes `True` hence lhs is `False`, whereas `(p || (r && q))` is `False` and hence rhs is `True`.

Similar is the case with `(True,False,False)` in which lhs is `True` and rhs is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement `r xor p xor q`? That should have 4 True and 4 False.

```
[r /= (p /= q) | let bools = [True, False], r <- bools, p <- bools, q <- bools]
```

Or if you are proving xor is associative, then:

```
[(r /= (p /= q)) == ((r /= p) /= q) |
 let bools = [True, False], r <- bools, p <- bools, q <- bools]
```

This one does have all 8 True